# Call Delphi DLL Function from C# Question on the Marshalling of Data Type (array of char / array of integer)

Tags: c#, delphi, marshalling

Call Delphi DLL Function from C#
Marshalling of Data Type (array of char / array of integer)

delphi function

```pascal
type
 _InputPW = array[0..39] of char;
 _InputPW_Len = array[0..1] of integer;

 _OutPW = array[0..64] of char;
 _OutPW_Len = array[0..1] of integer;

 function call_encrypt_pw(Const m_InputPW : _InputPW;
                          Const m_InputPW_Len : _InputPW_Len;
                          Const m_ResultPW : _OutPW;
                          Const m_ResultPW_Len : _OutPW_Len
                          ):integer;stdcall;
                          external 'Ext.dll' name 'call_encrypt_pw';
```

C# Code

```cs
[DllImport(@"Ext.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
public static extern int call_encrypt_pw(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 40)] string input, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 2)] int[] input_len, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 65)] out string output, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 2)] out int[] output_len
);
```

output / output_len
null return.

I think it's the Marshalling problem.

Please advise me how to modify the code.

Comment: Which version of Delphi is being used? In Delphi 2007 and earlier, `Char` is `AnsiChar`. In Delphi 2009 and later, `Char` is `WideChar`. Marshaling the strings would be easier if the Delphi code took simple `PChar` pointers instead of `Char[]` arrays. And why are `_InputPW_Len` and `_OutPW_Len` declared as 2-element arrays instead of as single `integer`s?

Comment: Delphi 2007 - I didn't create the DLL file.

Comment: Third arg should be StringBuilder, with the `out` specifier removed. That assumes that it will be null terminated which may not be the case. You need to check with the dll documentation. And the fourth arg must also not have `out`. Sorting that out just makes sure that the binary API matches. That's like the syntax of the interface. But you also need to sort out the semantics, in other words the meaning of the arguments, and how you must prepare them when calling, and interpret them on return. In short, you have not presented enough information for anyone to know how to call this function.